# Limit the sum of 2 processes cpu usage?

Tags: cpu

2 processes, call it A and B
A has high priority，B has low priority
I want to limit total cpu usage of these 2 processes under 80%

Sometimes A has nothing to do，cpu usage is 0%, at this time, I hope B execute and take up 80% cpu
Sometimes A is working，cpu usage is 80%, at this time, I hope B do nothing and not use cpu(or use only a little, 1%)
Sometimes A take up 30% cpu, at this time, B should take up 50% cpu

I am under Ubuntu 20.04, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To be this exact you probably need to use *cgroups*.

Here is a quick example I tested on Ubuntu 20.04.  For simplicity, this is a single cpu VM and all commands were run as root.

- install tools

```
apt-get install cgroup-tools stress
```

- create a hierarchy of cgroups that will be cpu limited.  The parent is named `max80` and it has `A` and `B` beneath it.

```
cgcreate -g cpu:max80/A -g cpu:max80/B
```

- limit the parent cgroup `max80` to 80% of the CPU.

```
echo 1000000 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/max80/cpu.cfs_period_us
echo  800000 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/max80/cpu.cfs_quota_us
```

- limit the child cgroup `B` to have 10% of shares. You mentioned 1% in your post, but 10% is easier to show.  `B` will use all the available CPU, but if there is contention with processes in `A` then it will be limited to 10%.

```
echo $((1024 * 10 / 100 )) > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/max80/B/cpu.shares
```

**In action**

- run a `stress` process in just `A`.  The CPU usage will be 80% for the `stress` process doing the work.

```
root@ubuntu:~# cgexec -g cpu:max80/A stress --cpu 1 &
[1] 2040
stress: info: [2040] dispatching hogs: 1 cpu, 0 io, 0 vm, 0 hdd
root@ubuntu:~# ps -o pid,%cpu,cmd --sort -%cpu -p $(pidof stress)
    PID %CPU CMD
   2041 80.4 stress --cpu 1
   2040  0.0 stress --cpu 1
root@ubuntu:~# killall stress
```

- run a `stress` process in just `B`.  The CPU usage will be 80%.

```
root@ubuntu:~# cgexec -g cpu:max80/B stress --cpu 1 &
[1] 2065
stress: info: [2065] dispatching hogs: 1 cpu, 0 io, 0 vm, 0 hdd
root@ubuntu:~# ps -o pid,%cpu,cmd --sort -%cpu -p $(pidof stress)
    PID %CPU CMD
   2066 80.6 stress --cpu 1
   2065  0.0 stress --cpu 1
root@ubuntu:~# killall stress
```

- run a `stress` process in `A` and `B`.  The CPU usage will be split 90%/10%.

```
root@ubuntu:~# cgexec -g cpu:max80/A stress --cpu 1 &
[1] 2078
stress: info: [2078] dispatching hogs: 1 cpu, 0 io, 0 vm, 0 hdd
root@ubuntu:~# cgexec -g cpu:max80/B stress --cpu 1 &
[2] 2080
stress: info: [2080] dispatching hogs: 1 cpu, 0 io, 0 vm, 0 hdd
root@ubuntu:~# ps -o pid,%cpu,cmd --sort -%cpu -p $(pidof stress)
    PID %CPU CMD
   2079 71.9 stress --cpu 1
   2081  7.2 stress --cpu 1
   2078  0.0 stress --cpu 1
   2080  0.0 stress --cpu 1
root@ubuntu:~# killall stress
```

**Links**

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/cgroups
- https://linuxhint.com/limit_cpu_usage_process_linux/
- https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-cgroups-to-control-cpu-usage/
- https://scoutapm.com/blog/restricting-process-cpu-usage-using-nice-cpulimit-and-cgroups

Comment: Thanks, very detail! I tried it, it did limit cpu usage under 80%, but only for 1 cpu, my PC has 8 cpus, so it actually take up 80% of 800%, rest 7 cpus still idle. I hope it can use 80% of all cpus, so 800% * 80% = 640%, is there any way to do this?

Comment: I believe you would have to multiply the quota by the number of cores.  `echo  $((8 * 800000)) > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/max80/cpu.cfs_quota_us`.  If you are using `stress` to test then you need to increase the worker count `stress --cpu 8`.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, the priority of running programs can be changes with the `renice`  command. You can read about the command typing `man renice` on the terminal. Tuturials on the internet will get you up to speed in gaining an understanding of how this works, e.g. [Tecmint](https://www.tecmint.com/set-linux-process-priority-using-nice-and-renice-commands/), [Computer Hope](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/renice.htm).